# Counting SSRS Report Executions (omitting Auto-Refresh counts)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am performing an analysis on the frequency of SSRS Report executions.

However, I need a method of separating reports ran 'manually' (by user interaction) and those that occur due to an 'Auto Refresh' (Auto Refresh Parameter on SSRS Report).

Is there any method of separating these out when querying the ReportServer Database, or at least ignoring any executions which were due to an Auto-Refresh event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could perhaps check the userid of the executing account. Not sure your setup but perhaps those auto refresh are run under an account that no other reports are? There is also an ‘interactive’ flag in the execution tables. If you don’t have subscriptions set up then perhaps that is a way as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the [ExecutionLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view) views in the Report Server database.  The fields you'll likely need to pay attention to are ItemAction and Source, but you'll need to determine which combinations you consider to be an execution.  I'd start with ItemAction="Render" and Source="Live", possibly also looking at Format(Web vs PDF, etc).

Best thing to do is play with a report and see what data it generates in the log table, and then determine which ones you are interested in capturing.